# Python: Sort by numbers within a list of strings?

Tags: python

I have a multiline text file, which I have extracted the data out into a list.

Each row has text and a number. I want to order the row by highest to lowest value.

IE

```
chris: 12
dave: 3
phil: 19
```

into

```
['phill: 19', 'chris: 12', 'dave': 3]
```

Here is what i have so far:

```
def highest_score():
    values = []
    order = []

    for line in open('my_file.txt'):
        values.append(line.rstrip())

    for line in values:
        order.append([int(s) for s in line.split() if s.isdigit()])

    print(sorted(order, reverse=True))
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is it not in the in the title?

Comment: I answered exactly the same question 2 days ago. I believe this is a common homework assignment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will do:

```
def highest_score():

    with open('my_file.txt') as myfile:
        values = myfile.readlines()

    values.sort(key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[1].strip()), reverse=True)

    return values
```

This will work with all types of strings as long as `:` is the separator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda function for this, splitting the string (assuming the number will always be after the space. If not, you can use the regex that you think would work).

I'm also assuming you have a typo in the question and that this:

```
['phill: 19', 'chris: 12', 'dave': 3]
```

should be this:

```
['phill: 19', 'chris: 12', 'dave: 3']
```

Code example for sorting with lambda:

```
my_list = ['phill: 19', 'chris: 12', 'dave: 33']

sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]), reverse=True)
```